# Why doesn't updating a particle settings object `frame_start` field work? (in Blender 2.8)

Tags: python, particles

I am creating a ParticleSettings object from python (Blender 2.8). All of the properties are set correctly but for `frame_start`, which does not change. Any ideas of why?

```
ps = modifier.particle_system.settings
ps.count = num_particles
ps.frame_start = explosion_frame
ps.frame_end = explosion_frame + 2
ps.lifetime = FPS * 3
ps.emit_from = 'VOLUME'
ps.normal_factor = 3
ps.tangent_phase = 0.5
ps.tangent_factor = 3
print(ps.count, ps.frame_start, ps.frame_end, ps.lifetime, ps.emit_from, ps.normal_factor, ps.tangent_phase, ps.tangent_factor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was setting `frame_start` first, to a value greater than the current (at the time) `frame_end`. `frame_start` needs to be less or equal than `frame_end`. The following version does work.

```
ps = modifier.particle_system.settings
ps.frame_end = explosion_frame + 2
ps.frame_start = explosion_frame
```